# PDO no guarda valores de query

Tags: php, html, mysql, pdo

Tengo un html para registro de usuarios en un sistema (signup.html), y con un formulario mando los datos a un PHP que ejecuta una consulta para guardarlos en la base de datos (signup.php), pero cuando reviso la tabla donde deberia guardarse el registro no hay nada.

Este es mi formulario (signup.html):

```
<form action="signup.php" method="post" id="form_login" >
    <div class="form-group has-feedback">
        <input name="name" type="text" id="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Nombre(s)" >
        <input name="lastname" type="text" id="lastname" class="form-control" placeholder="Apellido(s)" >
        <span class="fa fa-user form-control-feedback"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group has-feedback">
        <input name="username" type="text" id="username" class="form-control" placeholder="Nombre de usuario" >
        <span class="fa fa-user form-control-feedback"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group has-feedback">
        <input name="password" type="password" id="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Contrase単a">
        <span class="fa fa-lock form-control-feedback"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group has-feedback">
        <input name="password" type="password" id="confirm_password" class="form-control" placeholder="Confirmar contrase単a">
        <span id="span_contrasena" class="fa fa-lock form-control-feedback"></span><br id="br">
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-4">
            <button type="submit" name="Submit" id="enviar" class="btn btn-primary btn-flat">Finalizar registro</button><br><br>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Este es el PHP que lo recibe y ejecuta la consulta (signup.php):

```
require_once("../db_con.php");
$pass = password_hash($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
$sql = "INSERT INTO usuarios (usuario, nombre, apellido, pass) VALUES ( :usuario, :nombre, :apellido, :pass )";
$pdo_statement = $pdo_conn->prepare( $sql );
$result = $pdo_statement->execute( array( ':usuario'=>$_POST['username'], ':nombre'=>$_POST['name'], ':apellido'=>$_POST['lastname'], ':pass'=>$pass ) );
if (!empty($result) ){
    echo "lelel";
    //header('location:../index.html');
}
else{
    echo "No se guardo el registro<br/>";
    print_r($pdo_conn->errorInfo());
}
```

Y este es el PHP para la conexion a la BD:

```
try{
$hostname = "Localhost";
$username = "aabdesig_admin";
$password = "aabdesign2018";
$database = "aabdesig_registros";
$pdo_conn = new PDO( 'mysql:host=Localhost;dbname=aabdesig_registros', $username, $password );} catch (PDOException $e) {
print "¡Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
die();
```

}

Cuando reviso el PHP en el explorador esto es lo que imprime:

> No se guardo el registro
>
> Array ( [0] => 00000 [1] => [2] => )

Revise acerca de ese error de PDO y dice que ese array sale cuando todo se ejecuto de forma correcta pero aun asi no esta el registro en mi DB.

De antemano muchas gracias por sus respuestas.

Comment: ¿Podrias hacer un  $pdo_statement->errorInfo(); y mostrar el error que te da en lugar de $pdo_conn->errorInfo(); ? El método que usas para ver errores lo tienes que usar sobre el objeto PDOStatement , de lo contrario no veras información del error de la sentencia preparada.

Comment: Wow, gracias amigo, ahora si puedo ver el error, pero el error es "Field 'id' doesn't have a default value" y ese campo lo tengo como autoincrement

Comment: Si confirmas que el campo está puesto como clave primaria y auto_increment puede que sea que Mysql está configurado en modo estricto. Prueba a buscar en archivo de configuración de Mysql ( my.cnf / my.ini) la linea donde pone sql-mode='[cadena_de_configuracion]'  y quita de la cadena STRICT_ALL_TABLES y STRICT_TRANS_TABLES . Tras eso reinicia Mysql y prueba si te funciona.

Comment: Si no quieres cambiar la configuración, puedes indicar un valor `NULL` para la columna autoincrement: `$sql = "INSERT INTO usuarios (id, usuario, nombre, apellido, pass) VALUES (NULL, :usuario, :nombre, :apellido, :pass )";` eso debería hacer que el valor se autoincremente y evitaría el error. No lo he probado, pero debería funcionar.